# How to hide Object movement in 2d animation in blender?

Tags: animation, image, keyframes, 2d

I am trying to move an object (Image as a plane ) in 2d amination from point A to point B. Created a 20 sec video here : https://youtu.be/bOoxcpsf3hc

I can move the object, but I don't want the object to "appear" moving. At frame 30, object is at point A. At frame 60, object is at point B. But it seems that object is moving from point A to point B. I don't want that. I want that till frame 30 to 59, object remains at point A, and suddenly, at frame 60, it moves to point B. Is it possible?

I am using 2d animation in Blender, using Grease Pencil.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common methods to achieve this result: one is to select the keyframes, right click and change their interpolation mode from Bezier, to Constant.

The other method is to select the first keyframe, shift D to duplicate it and move it to frame 59.